# Can you keep the 0s when parsing a string from an int? c#

Tags: c#, winforms, parsing

I'm making a 2d array of buttons, and want its tag to be its array position, including the starting 0s and ending 0s (e.g 01 or 2002)... is this possible?

```cs
Button[,] buttonGrid = new Button[11, 21];

Button gridButton = new Button
{
    Tag = int.Parse(yIndex.ToString() + xIndex.ToString()),
    BackColor = Color.LightGray,
    Enabled = true,
    Size = new Size(size, size),
    Location = new Point(25, 25)
};
```

I used a for loop to loop through each element in the array thats where the x and y index come from.

this will return 1,2,3 - 9 in the first row then 10, 11, 12, so on. but I want it to be 01, 02, 03 or 020.

Comment: if you want 020, then you don't want an `int` data type.  That's a string.  So...don't parse it to an `int`

Comment: can I set the tag using a string?

Comment: As per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) Tag is an object, so you can set whatever you need

Comment: You can also store an `int[]` in the tag and format it for display.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably not rely on string concatenation to create the tags. since you have no idea if "111" means `x=1, y=11` or `x=11, y=1` Tags are used internally to distinguish UI objects. Normally when converting two coordinates to a single index you would do a calculation like

```
var i = yIndex * width + xIndex;
```

and this can be reversed:

```
var yIndex = i / width;
var xIndex = i - yIndex * width;
```

If you want the number to be in the format XXYY, then you can simply use 100 as the width. If you want to convert this to a text-label you can use a format specifier when converting it to string, i.e. `i.ToString("0000")`

Answer (score 0):

If you need preceding zeros in your `int`, I would suggest you keep the position as a `string`. When you need to calculate it, just convert it to `int` temporarily and perform the calculations. You can assign anything in the `Tag`.